# How to hide selected term values in Views?

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type with a taxonomy field called Price. Authors create content based on this content type. While doing so they select from a Price list (two options). Either they can select 'Costs Money' or 'Free'.

In [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), I want to show the value (a rendered image) if it's set to "*costs money*" and NOT display the field if it's set to "*free*".

Is there an easy way to accomplish this in Views?

I'm using Views 3 and Drupal 7.

Comment: Maybe try [Views Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional). I haven't used it so can't tell more about this module.

Comment: You can use view rewrite result behavior for that specific field.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Apologies, you're right. I updated my question.

Comment: I'm noticing that when I don't specify a value sometimes it just doesn't show or take up any space by default, maybe depending on the field type?

@Rupesh could I rewrite the field to output "" (nothing) if it's set to 'Free'?...what would be the format for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the views feature "rewrite result", combined with a logic similar to the pseudo code that is below to implement the desired functionality:

```
if Price Term = 'Costs Money' then write the image tag related to 'Costs Money'
else write &nbsp;
```

Not sure if you'd actually need the else clause ...

**Note**: This requires the [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module , as described in https://www.drupal.org/node/482752#comment-4841554 also. Attention: this module only has an alfa version as of today, but it's used in over 71K sites anyway.

Comment: yes, this makes sense. However, where do you suggest I place the code for this? (in 'rewrite output of this field'?). Can I put php code in there? It looks like it just allows text and placeholders. Maybe you mean template.php or something...